# Odoo 8: Программное создание строк one2many на форме по событию on_change

Tags: python, odoo

Кто-нибудь знает как программно создать строки в списке *one2many* на форме по событию `on_change` и сразу увидеть эти созданные строки списка на форме (до сохранения всей формы)?

К примеру, есть заказ, в заказе есть поле `Партнер`.

Так же, на форме есть список (*one2many*) товаров.

Мне необходимо при изменении значения в поле "Партнер" формировать список товаров и сразу видеть этот созданный список на форме.

Подробно аналогичный вопрос изложен здесь https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/create-new-many2one-records-in-api-onchange-method-69837

Но у меня так и не получилось создать форму с программным интерактивным формированием списка. (Создание списка товаров при сохранении всего заказа целиком - с этим проблем нет). Кто-нибудь знает как решить данную проблему? Если ли примеры в odoo? В каком-нибудь модуле?

Answer (score 1):

Вся мудрость в   **self.slave_id += self.slave_id.new({'name': str(x), 'qty': x})**

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Master(models.Model):
    _name = 'att.master'

    name    = fields.Char("Name")
    qty     = fields.Integer("Qty")
    slave_id = fields.One2many('att.slave','master_id', 'slaves', copy=True )

    @api.onchange('name')
    def _on_change_name(self):
        if self.name:
            self.qty += 100
            print 'The on_change event was happened'
            for x in range(1,5,1):
                self.slave_id += self.slave_id.new({'name': str(x), 'qty': x})


class Slave(models.Model):
    _name = 'att.slave'

    master_id = fields.Many2one('att.master', ondelete='cascade', select=True )
    name = fields.Char("Name")
    qty = fields.Integer("Qty")
```

Master
            att.master

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="att_master_view_tree">
        <field name="name">List of master</field>
        <field name="model">att.master</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="List of master">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="qty"/>
                <field name="id"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!-- window action -->
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="att_master_list_action">
        <field name="name">Master</field>
        <field name="res_model">att.master</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="att_master_menuitem" name="Master"
              parent="att_menu_agreement"
              action="att_master_list_action"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Интересное решение. Не нашел метод `new` в документации. Я использую метод `create`: `self.slave_id.create({...})`

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще интересное решение на Apps store
Суть его в том, чтобы создавать шаблоны с перечнем товаров и потом, при создании документа, обращаться к перечню внесенных шаблонов и выбирать из него. Тогда в товарах появляется список с ценами и прочим.
Как раз, как в вопросе "К примеру, есть заказ, в заказе есть поле Партнер."
Я его конвертировал из Odoo в Flectra. Работает.
Не устраивает, что, при выборе, все ранее выбранные товары, затираются новыми. Но это дело, думаю, поправимое.